# How to use Twilio in Background mode on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, twilio, ios-background-mode

I have created an application for video streaming in React native, I used this library with latest version: [twilio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc).

In iOS, I can't use the camera when the app is in background mode, I don't know if I used camera in background or not.

Is this possible or not for iOS? Where can I find documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, camera does not work when an app goes to background. See more here:

> Camera usage is prohibited while in the background. If you attempt to start running a camera while in the background, the capture session sends an AVCaptureSessionWasInterruptedNotification with this interruption reason. If you don't explicitly call the stopRunning method, your startRunning request is preserved, and when your app comes back to foreground, you receive AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEndedNotification and your session starts running.

Comment: Where is this quote from?

Comment: How can I used pip(picture-in-picture) for Video streaming while app is in background mode with Twilio library in iOS?